# rails db column remember_token is not saved and always nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

Why am i unable to update a db column in rails?
Database has a column - 'remember_token' but update is not working on it ?

Result of DB migration

```
    ....
    ....
    ....

== 20140830041234 AddRememberTokenToUsers: migrating ==========================
-- add_column(:users, :remember_token, :string)
   -> 0.0010s
-- add_index(:users, :remember_token)
   -> 0.0000s
== 20140830041234 AddRememberTokenToUsers: migrated (0.0030s) =================
```

rails console - output !
**remember_token is nil after a direct assignment**

```
irb(main):063:0* user
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Test", email: "hb@c.co", created_at: "2014-09-01 22:52:02", updated_at: "2014-09-01 22:52:02", p
assword_digest: "$2a$10$/66wO2dBte/xCXqxk.UAo.v.7.XZjsBFA3AerAWkHp16...", remember_token: nil>
irb(main):064:0> User.digest('asdasd')
=> "85136c79cbf9fe36bb9d05d0639c70c265c18d37"
irb(main):065:0> user.remember_token = User.digest('asdasd')
=> "85136c79cbf9fe36bb9d05d0639c70c265c18d37"
irb(main):066:0>
irb(main):067:0* user
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Test", email: "hb@c.co", created_at: "2014-09-01 22:52:02", updated_at: "2014-09-01 22:52:02", p
assword_digest: "$2a$10$/66wO2dBte/xCXqxk.UAo.v.7.XZjsBFA3AerAWkHp16...", remember_token: nil>
irb(main):068:0>
```

**remember_token is nil after update_attributes**

```
irb(main):071:0> user.update_attributes(name: "Yahoo", remember_token: "will this get saved")
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mbegin transaction←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mUser Exists (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('hb@c.co') AND "u
sers"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (7.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mUPDATE "users" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 1←[0m  [["name", "Y
ahoo"], ["updated_at", Mon, 01 Sep 2014 23:12:59 UTC +00:00]]
  ←[1m←[35m (8.0ms)←[0m  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):072:0>
irb(main):073:0* user
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Yahoo", email: "hb@c.co", created_at: "2014-09-01 22:52:02", updated_at: "2014-09-01 23:12:59",
password_digest: "$2a$10$/66wO2dBte/xCXqxk.UAo.v.7.XZjsBFA3AerAWkHp16...", remember_token: nil>
```

**Below is the model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :remember_token
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    before_create :create_remember_token

    def User.new_remember_token
        SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    def User.digest(token)
        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
    end


private
    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end

end
```

**And just in case -- here is the controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    #@user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        # Handle a successful save.
            flash[:success] = "Welcome #{@user.name} to the Sample App!"
            redirect_to @user
        else
        render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,:password_confirmation, :remember_token)
    end
end
```

Comment: How does your model look? do you have any callbacks ?

Comment: Hi, yes there is a callback

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
 attr_accessor :remember_token  
 before_save { self.email = email.downcase }  
 before_create :create_remember_token  

`

Answer (score -2):

You have to add `:remember_token` to `attr_accessible` in your User model.

```
attr_accessible :remember_token
```

Comment: Thanks, I have it set

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessor :remember_token`

Comment: `attr_accessor` != `attr_accessible`!!!

Comment: also, the poster is using strong_params in their code - so they do not need `attr_accessible`.

Answer (score -2):

it seems that the `:remember_token` attribute has not been picked up by rails. Try to restart the console and it might work.

Comment: Tried that a few time :(